# Accessing nested arrays and translating certain key values with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i have this function for translating using openai

```
function translate($text, $language, $openai)
{
    $prompt = "translate this text into $language:\n\n" . $text;
    $response = $openai
        ->completions()
        ->create([
            "model" => "text-davinci-003",
            "prompt" => $prompt,
            "temperature" => 0.5,
            "max_tokens" => 1024,
            "n" => 1,
            "stop" => '\n\n',
        ]);
    $translatedText = $response["choices"][0]["text"];
    return ($translatedText);
}
```

and also have this variable which accepts the items of an array like this

```
$previousText = $result['story']['content']['text']['content']
```

so when I print out I get

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => paragraph
            [content] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => neuer Text
                            [type] => text
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => paragraph
            [content] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => zweiter Text
                            [type] => text
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

now what I have been doing manually to translate each item of the array as

```
$previousText = $result['story']['content']['text']['content'][0]['content'][0]['text'];

$previousText = $result['story']['content']['text']['content'][1]['content'][0]['text'];
```

respectively and then call

```
translate($previousText,'en',$openai);
```

but I want to translate all the instances in the array at once using

```
$previousText = $result['story']['content']['text']['content']
```